# shutdown alll nodes

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to shutdown all nodes from within a ros node. ros::shutdown() kills the current node but does not kill the other nodes.

I know that all nodes can be killed using the terminal and through the launch file. But I test if a certain condition is met and only in such a circumstance I want all the nodes to shutdown.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292456/shutdown-alll-nodes/) by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2018-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If all your nodes are launched by a single launch file, you could make your checking node [required](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) and let it stop itself to take down the whole launch file. If you have several launch files, have a required node in each launch and connect the killer nodes with [bonds](http://wiki.ros.org/bond).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2018-05-28**:
Thanks a lot! I didn't know of this parameter.